# How do you migrate trial content from Video Indexer to a Paid account?

Tags: azure, azure-video-indexer

I have a number of videos in my Video Indexer Trial account that I would like to move over to a Paid account. I tried following the instructions in https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/media-services/video-indexer/connect-to-azure#import-your-content-from-the-trial-account but this appears to only work if you setup your trial account with Azure AD.

Since I setup the Trial account with a Personal Microsoft Account, I don't see an option to import my existing content into a new account. I've setup everything manually in Azure for a new account (including Azure AD), but I don't want to lose the content from my Trial account.

Is there a way to import the Trial account content from Video Indexer into a paid account when your trial account was setup with a Personal Account? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a way to import your media between different accounts, even if you are using two different authentication methods(Personal Microsoft Account/Gamil and Azure AD).

Use [this link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/media-services/video-indexer/invite-users) to learn how to invite your Azure AD user into your Personal Microsoft Account as a contributor and appoint yourself to be an owner in the account.
Then access your AAD account, choose the trail account you wish to move to be a paid account, click the 'create unlimited account' this time you should have the option to check the "import my media' checkbox.

Answer (score 0):

Our recommendation is to follow the Prerequisites list section as described here
in order to make sure the user has all the correct permissions on the account.
Connecting to Azure can also be done with a manual Flow. This will require the user to be with either an Owner role, or both Contributor and User Access Administrator roles as described in this link